# Is it possible to perform arithmetic operation on attribute value in XML

Tags: android

Usually, if I want to make one of my view having the same height of action bar, I can do

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

The above will work perfectly fine, whether we are in landscape or portrait mode (Action bar is having different size in landscape and portrait mode)

However, what if I want to have my view, having **2x of the height of action bar**. Is it possible I can have something like

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize * 2">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I apply mathematical operations to Android dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101178/how-do-i-apply-mathematical-operations-to-android-dimensions)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are also a few familiar math operators that you may find useful:

`*` Multiplies two numeric values

`div` Divides two numeric values and returns the integer result

`mod` Divides two numeric values and returns the integer remainder

`+` Adds two numeric values

`-` Subtracts two numeric values

Comment: Can you provide an example? `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize div 2"` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: The correct answer in case of Android layout attributes is [no](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8101549/5908572), although in *XSLT* you can do that