# Mathematical operations in Android layout attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use following otherwise my custom widget was overlapped by a `Toolbar`:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

But I want to have additional margin, say 10dp. I cannot do something like:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize + 10dp"
```

because + is not allowed character there. Is there any other way except coding a rule programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your ViewGroup into another one just to add the 10dp margin. Not optimal but that would work.

Comment: I see. Container, then my custom view. Interesting is that standard containers do not need sucg margin-top, the can handle NoActionBar theme authomaticaly. But I have no idea how to detect this situation in my custom view.

Answer (score 1):

Layout XML files do not support expressions. So You can't Perform exepression on it. You can perform in `XSLT`.

There is one trick describe below.

`margin + padding` as describe in this Answer.

**Source :** [How do I apply mathematical operations to Android dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101178/how-do-i-apply-mathematical-operations-to-android-dimensions)